# identify this book about a human turned into a god by aliens

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, space, psychic

I am wracking my brain trying to figure out the name of this sci-fi novel and its author that I read back in the early to mid-1980s.

The book is about an ordinary man who, during some sort of interstellar space exploration (the book takes place pretty far into the future) is involved in some sort of accident or something and almost dies. He would've died had not an alien or aliens saved him.
This alien (or aliens) is a god compared to humans and this man is given god-like powers too, as well as a non-corporeal body.

The main character was in the military. If I remember correctly, he already had some sort of psychic abilities, and he used them as a member of the military. If I recall correctly, there's a scene where a bunch of enemy soldiers are walking along the hull of a spaceship, and they try to drill through it. The main character uses his mental powers to make one enemy soldier kill another with his drill. And this was *before* he gets turned into a god by aliens!

Other than that, all I remember is that he saves three alien civilizations when their star goes supernova (or something like that). I wish I could remember more.

It was a paperback that I read, so I don't know if there ever was a hardcover or not. I don't know the title of the book or the author, unfortunately, but if someone told me I'd be able to say, yep that's it, or nope that's not it.

Comment: I found your question on [LibraryThing](http://www.librarything.com/topic/69894) ^_^. You should add that part about the man becoming non-corporeal here.

Comment: Could be Frank Herbert's *The Godmakers*. Most everything fits - though sometimes borderline - with the exception of the drilling scene. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godmakers_%28novel%29) this novel is based on four earlier short stories. I haven't read them, but perhaps your story is one of them?

Comment: Wow, that is pretty close. It's not it though, but I think whoever the author is I'm thinking of may have ripped Herbert off a little.

Comment: Probably not it, but I'll leave as a comment, just in case... sounds a little like "Stranger in a Strange Land " by Heinlein (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_in_a_Strange_Land).  There's a space accident origin story, psychic powers, "miracles", action from beyond the grave.  Nothing about supernovae, nor psychic drill murders, though.

Answer (score 4):

The Dahak series matches about half of your description.  The first book is **Mutineer's Moon** by David Weber.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutineers%27_Moon

> ... until the Earthling's early space program sends up one Lieutenant
>   Commander Colin MacIntyre to map the dark side of the heavenly body
>   Dahak had camouflaged itself as—the Moon, as a "dress rehearsal" for a
>   similar trip scheduled for Mars.
>
> His mission is hijacked by Dahak and his death is faked; had MacIntyre
>   returned with his data, Dahak’s cover would have been blown. While
>   aboard, Dahak (the AI, not the vessel proper) explains the situation
>   to MacIntyre, and prevails upon him to, as a descendant of the
>   loyalists, become Dahak’s newest captain ...

Matches:

1. Military pilot doing normal patrol/interception of bad guys, flies
   by the Moon, and taken into a cavernous opening in the moon
2. He is remade by the ship's on-board AI, Dahak, so he is nearly
   indestructible and has many "super-human" powers
3. Being remade nearly kills him
4. Dahak is able to do many things based simply upon a thought by the
   person brought aboard.
5. There is combat as the "mutineers" attempt to both leave and board
   the ship Dahak.
6. Through the course of the series, Dahak and the human crew save
   Terrestrial humanity and other civilizations from a rampaging alien hoard intent
   on annihilating all other intelligent life.
7. There is a Nova at the original home star of the civilization that
   built Dahak.  The humans and Dahak trying to salvage the remains of
   the civilization had to work hard to salvage as much as possible.

Doesn't Match:

1. No non-corporeal
2. No psychic powers

Comment: if correct, this book was also the answer to this later question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95907/looking-for-a-book-about-the-moon-being-a-spaceship-with-an-ai

Comment: Though there was a nova (or two) in the Dahak series, it was not the nova that did in the original civilization that built Dahak.